# Error connecting to the database (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have cloned a website from github and I am trying to connect my database (MongoDB) with website but its giving an error

My database file:
db.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
try {
  mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://AhmedHassan:Knight007@cluster0.ofzz68w.mongodb.net/TestDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  });
  console.log("Database Connected Successfully");
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Database Not Connected");
}
```

My app file:
app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

// Import Router
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const categoryRouter = require("./routes/categories");
const productRouter = require("./routes/products");
const brainTreeRouter = require("./routes/braintree");
const orderRouter = require("./routes/orders");
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
const customizeRouter = require("./routes/customize");
// Import Auth middleware for check user login or not~
const { loginCheck } = require("./middleware/auth");
const CreateAllFolder = require("./config/uploadFolderCreateScript");

/* Create All Uploads Folder if not exists | For Uploading Images */
CreateAllFolder();

// Database Connection
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() =>
    console.log(
      "==============Mongodb Database Connected Successfully=============="
    )
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log("Database Not Connected !!!"));

// Middleware
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

// Routes
app.use("/api", authRouter);
app.use("/api/user", usersRouter);
app.use("/api/category", categoryRouter);
app.use("/api/product", productRouter);
app.use("/api", brainTreeRouter);
app.use("/api/order", orderRouter);
app.use("/api/customize", customizeRouter);

// Run Server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on ", PORT);
});
```

Here are pictures:

01_ After Running the server from terminal i.e, "npm run start:dev"
[When Server Starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqVo6.png)

02_ After Registering a user from front-end:
[After registering a user i.e sending data to Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUx2a.png)

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: What is the error? Better use `console.log(err)` instead of `console.log("Database Not Connected !!!")` which does not provide any useful information.

Comment: The following error is given after console.log(err)
   MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB? Error message `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017` does not match to connection string `mongodb+srv://AhmedHassan:Knight007@cluster0.ofzz68w.mongodb.net/TestDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority` Host "cluster0.ofzz68w.mongodb.net"  is not "127.0.0.1:27017"

Comment: Does this mean this website is connected to the local MongoDB service, not online?

Comment: I don't know. Your question has two different `mongoose.connect(...)` First you should evaluate from which one you get the error.